# How to make fade transition faster css3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm changing my background image every 7 seconds, and I'm doing it with a fade transition. The problem is that the transition takes too long, so there is a time gap between every image where the background is totally white. I tried changing the transition duration property, but it doesn't have any effect.

SCSS

```
.slide_photo {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    margin: 52px 0 0 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), image-url('landing1.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -webkit-animation: fade 7s infinite;
    -moz-animation: fade 7s infinite;
    -o-animation: fade 7s infinite;
    animation: fade 7s infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var slide_images = ["landing1.jpg", "landing2.jpg", "landing3.jpg", "landing4.jpg"];
var slide_count = 0;


$(document).ready(function() {

  setInterval(function() {
    slide_count = ++slide_count % slide_images.length;

    $('.slide_photo').css('background-image', 'linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url(\'' + slide_images[slide_count] + '\')');
  }, 7000);

});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container landing-container">
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: you can increase the range:`20%, 80% {
    opacity: 1;
  }` instead the initial 50%

Comment: `transition: all 0.1s linear 0;`

Comment: Decide how long the fade should last.  Then calculate what is the value proportionally to the time left for the fade.  It might be shoppy sometimes because of other javascript code but your fade will always take the same time.

Comment: Could you let me know what is not working with the answer a gave, so I will be able to adjust and you to accept?

Comment: @LGSon srry i forgot to mark it as correct, my bad :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest you drop script and do it all using CSS, as combining script and CSS will most likely get you issues with synchronization (of course, do it all with script will also solve synchronization)

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slide_photo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    animation: fade 28s infinite;
    opacity: 0;
}
.slide_photo.nr4 {
    background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url('http://placehold.it/150/f00');
    animation-delay: 21s;
}
.slide_photo.nr3 {
    background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url('http://placehold.it/150/');
    animation-delay: 14s;
}
.slide_photo.nr2 {
    background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url('http://placehold.it/150/00f');
    animation-delay: 7s;
}
.slide_photo.nr1 {
    background-image: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url('http://placehold.it/150/0f0');
    animation-delay: 0s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  22% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container landing-container">
  <div class="slide_photo nr1"></div>
  <div class="slide_photo nr2"></div>
  <div class="slide_photo nr3"></div>
  <div class="slide_photo nr4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In you script, the `setInverval` function is correctly set to 7000. But the duration values in your CSS seems wrong. Change it to something like this:

```
.slide_photo {
    ...
    -webkit-animation: fade .3s infinite;
    -moz-animation: fade .3s infinite;
    -o-animation: fade .3s infinite;
    animation: fade .3s infinite;
}
```

Comment: the duration on the css and js has to be equal.