# css3 animate works for bg color but no for bg image in FF and Edge

Tags: css, animation, background

I'm animating/changing background image of .hero div and I want smooth transitions between them so i used 3.3% keyframes to achieve it. With bg colors only it works fine in every browser but when i use background:url("someimg.jpg") It works only in Chrome. Firefox and Edge ignore the 3.3% keyframe transition.

```
 .hero{
    height:600px;
    width: 100%;
    background:red;
      animation: bg 20s  ease infinite;
}
@keyframes bg {
  0% {   
background: red;
}
  30% {   
      background: red;
}
      33.3% {   
      background: blue;
}
          63.3% {   
      background: blue;
}
          66.6% {   
      background: green;
}
              96.6% {   
      background: green;
}
                  100% {   
      background: red;
}
}
```

Comment: `background-image` is not an animateable property (still Chrome does)

Comment: If you want to fade images, you can do it like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41751986/how-to-make-fade-transition-faster-css3

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316527/full-background-image-with-fade-effect